# exclude influence of variable in two state statistical analysis/determine statistical difference between two groups

Tags: statistics

I have a chemical system that is very sensitive to a certain variable. Depending on that variable the end result will end up in either one of two states. That variable itself might be dependant of several other environmental variables.
The experiment will generate 1000+ results, each of which can be either in state 1 or in state 2. I am trying to determine the influence of other variables on the preference to be in state 1 or state 2. Arbitrary examples might be "amount of light", "Direction of the airflow" or "position of sample compared to CO2 flow origin".

Now lets say I changed 1 variable and I do a comparison of the amount of results being in state 1 and the amount being in state 2. Which test can I use to determine if these two groups are the same or if they differ significantly enough to be deemed "different"?

For example I do my experiment in bright light or absolute darkness and I find that the light side has 460 results of state 1 and 880 results of state 2 and the dark side has 550 results of state 1 and 700 results of state 2 (and cookies). If I set state 1 to -1 and state 2 to 1 the average will be: light=0.313 with a SD of 0.0259 and darkness=0.120 with a sd of 0.0281. Just looking at this would suggest that they are different but how do I PROVE this??

Comment: Might be a better question for crossvalidated (or stats) .StackExchange.

Comment: @mathreadler: In my view, the _subject matter_ of this post seems totally appropriate for the 'statistics' tag on our site. The difficulty is that it shows _no attempted solution._

Answer (score 0):

First, you will not *prove* anything by testing a statistical hypothesis.
You will find out whether the data seem consistent with Light and Dark
results being the same.

In Light you have $460$ 1's and $880$ 2'2, so the observed proportion of 1's is 
$\hat p_L = 460/(460 + 880) = 0.343.$

In Dark you have, $\hat p_D = 550/(550+700) = 0.440$

You want to test whether these data are consistent with the null hypothesis
$H_0: p_L = p_D$ that the proportions of 1's is the same in the two populations,
against $H_a: p_L \ne p_D.$

With these sample sizes, you can use a 'z-test for two proportions (pooled)'
according to the formula in the [*Wikipedia page on hypothesis testing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing), shown in
a table about half-way through the article. [You may also find this formula
lurking on unread pages of your statistics textbook.]

There are various on-line
calculators for this standard statistical test. 
Output from Minitab 17
statistical software is shown below:

```
Test for Two Proportions 

Sample    X     N  Sample p
1       460  1340  0.343284
2       550  1250  0.440000

Difference = p (1) - p (2)
Estimate for difference:  -0.0967164

Test for difference = 0 (vs ≠ 0):  Z = -5.04  P-Value = 0.000
```

The P-value is less than 0.0005 (printed as `0.000`). This means that
if $H_0$ were true there are less than 5 chances in 10,000 that
data would give $\hat p_L$ and $\hat p_D$ as far apart as in your data.
Your data are not consistent with $H_0.$ You have the choice to believe
that $H_0$ is true or that a very unlikely outcome has occurred in your data.

[BTW, these seem to be fake data from an exercise in a textbook,
instead of data from an actual experiment. Either that, or you have
rounded real data for posting here. There is about 1 chance in 10,000
that all four counts in an actual experiment would be numbers ending in 0.]

Comment: It is a real experiment but the data I posted is not. It has to be counted by hand (and electron microscope) and that will take some time. I only posted that as an example to better illustrate my problem (which is why I didn't make an attempt at testing the Null hypothesis). We are testing 5 variables vs our control experiment so you can imagine the mind numbing time spend counting. Thanks for the help

Comment: Understand about the fake data for illustration. _Want to make sure you understand the procedure for testing two proportions._ If feasible, I suggest you rotate different kinds of counts in batches of a few hundred. Do comparison tests sequentially. Depending on the size of the true difference, you may need smaller samples. In your fake data, $n > 1000$ was overkill. (For smaller differences btw $\hat p$'s, you may need $n > 1000.$) P-val around 0.01 should be enough to be reasonably sure and satisfy journal referees.

Comment: well, for one experiment n>1000 would definitely be overkill. Preliminary results gave 282 structures of state 1 vs 97 of state 2 against 172 of state 1 vs 153 of state 2. 
This experiment is to show that if we want to design a self organizing nano structure we need to factor in several variables that might seem far fetched. I'll let you know about the results (probably on saturday)